# how to change default delete date in lotus notes for emails?

Tags: lotus-notes

I am using Lotus Notes as my email client, and how to change the defailt email delete date to something new so my older emails don't get deleted after pre-defined date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

go to TOOLS -> Change Delete Date , you can put any number of days to change the default delete date  of selected email.

Answer (score 0):

Lotus Notes email does not automatically delete email - There is no "default delete date".

It does have a setting to automatically delete email from your Trash folder after a specified amount of hours (but mail only gets put in the Trash if you delete it).  You can find this setting by clicking More >> Preferences... "Delete documents in my Trash folder after __  hours"